# I installed Wordpress on my localhost and when i'm trying to view my own site it throws a 404

Tags: wordpress

I installed Wordpress on my Computer with MAMP. and when I'm trying to view my own site by clicking "View Site" I'm coming back to the root file directory instead of seeing any kind of a site. can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it showing your root file directory or is it returning a 404 error?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `content` (web pages), and assign a file as `index document` (`index.html`, `index.php`, etc...). Otherwise you will be presented with a `directory listing` (as you received).